# Possible to match argument by type in Erlang?

Tags: erlang

I'm wondering if it's possible to have a function that does different things for different argument types, including user-defined type.

This is an example of what I want to do:

```
myfunction(myType i) ->
    dothis;
myfunction(int s) ->
    dothat.
```

Is this possible and if it is, what is the syntax for doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is true that erlang does not offer the ability to define types, but one can consider that a type may be a structure built on primary erlang types for example a type `answer` could be of the form {From,Time,List} and in this case it is possible to use a mix of pattern matching and primary type test:

```
myfunction({From,Time,List}) when is_pid(From), is_integer(Time), Time >= 0, is_list(List) ->
    dothis;
myfunction(I) when is_integer(I) ->
    dothat.
```

and to be closer than the simple type test you are looking for, you can use a macro for testing

```
-define(IS_ANSWER(From,Time,List), (is_pid(From)), is_integer(Time), Time >= 0, is_list(List)).

myfunction({From,Time,List}) when ?IS_ANSWER(From,Time,List) ->
        answer;
myfunction(I) when is_integer(I) ->
        integer.
```

or even

```
-define(IS_ANSWER(A), (is_tuple(A) andalso size(A) == 3 andalso is_pid(element(1,A)) andalso is_integer(element(2,A)) andalso element(2,A) >= 0 andalso is_list(element(3,A)))).

myfunction(A) when ?IS_ANSWER(A) ->
        answer;
myfunction(A) when is_integer(A) ->
        integer.
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot define your own datatypes in Erlang so the first clause is impossible. You do type testing in the *guard* so the 2nd would become:

```
my_function(S) when is_integer(S) ->
    dothat.
```

What can do in the *guard* is very restricted and it consists of simple tests, for example type tests. Read about [Guard Sequences](http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/expressions.html#id80116).

Comment: The first case could be simulated by using tagged tuples and pattern matching, e.g. function({typename, Value}) -> ok.  Or, of course, using records and the is_record guard.

Comment: @Chris yes you normally do simulate it using tagged tuples or records. I was just pointing out that there are no *real* user defined types.